# Valign WebPartZone Sharepoint 2007

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, web-part

We're currently running a 2007 SharePoint setup. I have a site with two columns populated with different content.

The one on the left is holding a rather large Picture. The one to the right is showing a list view.

Now, my problem is the left column does not align vertically. This means the list view is centered compared to the picture, this isn't really what I wanted.

I tried inspecting the webpart zone to see if would be able to target it using CSS, but there's no id nor a class associated with the table.

It's not an option to use SPD as we're quite limited in our access to the server side.

Any ideas are more than welcome!

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried modifying the web part to have a fixed height?

From http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint-server-help/modify-shared-web-parts-HA001160706.aspx :

On the page that you want to edit, click Edit Page in the Actions list.
In the shared view, click the arrow for the Web Part you want to modify, and then click Modify Shared Web Part.
You can also click Modify Shared Page at the top of the page, point to Modify Shared Web Parts, and then click the Web Part you want to modify.

NOTE   To switch to the shared view from the personal view, click Modify My Page and then click Shared View.

The page opens in design mode with the selected Web Part outlined with a dotted yellow line. The properties for the Web Part are displayed in a pane that opens on the right side of the page.

In the pane for the Web Part, click Appearance.
In the Height section, click Yes to fix the height of the Web Part, click the units from the drop-down list, and then type the height limit in the text box.

Comment: Please provide more details.